# Variable does not exist in context, yet it is clearly defined

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

In the image below, you can see that I am debugging my code and the variable `y1` should be defined.  However, I am not getting any exceptions and the variable seems not to exist!  Why doesn't visual studio recognize my variable?  I believe there must be a problem with my installation; can anyone else confirm?

[image]

Ref. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bgu7.gif

Comment: Are you compiled in release mode?  Sometimes the optimizer can eliminate variable names in release mode.

Comment: Did you try to remove and readd that Watch?

Comment: @jlew it doesn't even need to be in release mode.  That optimization is done even in debug mode.

Comment: @jlew Wow, I never knew that.  After changing from my "Test" release mode to "Debug" I can see the variable now...  Strange stuff.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler can prove that the variable is never read, so it doesn't even bother to create it since it knows that it is never used.  If you alter the code to actually use the variable that optimization won't happen, and you'll be able to observe the variable through the debugger.

Comment: Or change to "Debug" release mode, per the original poster's experience (see comments above).

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(variableName);` can help too. It can force the optimiser to keep the variable longer, and it writes the value to your Output window (so you can see it there, if all else fails).